# QMenu QThread Implementation error

Tags: qt

I am trying to move my QSystemTrayIcon  module to a separate thread. I am getting the below error while running the application. The Initialize() method addAction causing the error.

**QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice**

My sample code snippets:

Declared the global variable
     QMenu myMenu;

Member Variable in the header file
     QAction* openFile;

In the constructor
     openFile = new QAction(parent);

```
Initialize() 
{
myMenu.addAction(openFile);
}

 void myApp::run()
 {
     Initialize()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must **not** use any GUI-related classes outside your main thread, i.e. the one `QApplication` was created in. Hence you cannot move your `QSystemTrayIcon` stuff in a separate thread.  And no, there is no workaround.

Comment: its a bad news.. I want to move my QSystemTrayIcon  to a separate thread because of performance issue

Comment: The TrayIcon menus are not displaying if some functionality is running at the background Menus will display after the process completion. Our application is single thread application

Comment: @Kolappan: Then move this “background functionality” into a thread, after all its not really “background” if it blocks the menus. And make sure to read the **whole** [Qt Thread support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html) guide before doing so, or else you'll see your application crashing at other places because you try to access GUI elements from background threads.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this problem backwards. The reason that "The TrayIcon menus are not displaying if some functionality is running at the background Menus will display after the process completion." is because you are blocking the GUI thread when you wait for things. Do not block the GUI thread by waiting on things. Most of Qt provides signals that fire when things get accomplished (when they succeed or fail). Those are the nonblocking APIs that you should be using.